WinVerifyTrust returns 0x800B0100 (TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE) but only when WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG provided
When WinVerifyTrust  is executed without WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG on the file with modified bytes, BadDigest 0x80096010  // TRUST_E_BAD_DIGEST returned as expected.
But when WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG is set and WinVerifyTrust executed on the same file then 0x800B0100 (TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE) returned.
Running signtool verify on the executable, returns BadDigest 0x80096010 as expected.
How to preroduce:
Run following code https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust
With WinTrustDataProvFlags ProvFlags = WinTrustDataProvFlags.HashOnlyFlag;
Why return value of WinVerifyTrust  with WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG is TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE despite the fact that signature exists?
UPDATE:
Based on this comment: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/Mozc-for-iOS/blob/45b0856ed8a22d5fa6b4471548389cbde4abcf10/src/win32/base/file_verifier.cc#L156 (I cant find any documentation that verifies that)
Executable has to be signed with WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG flag, otherwise WinVerifyTrust will return TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE.

"Why this is the case?" - What is "this" and why do you expect things to be different? Make sure to include a [mcve] when answering those questions.

I found that the wireguard.dll you referred has the sha256 Digest algorithm and RSA Digest encryption algorithm. So, TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE could mean the encryption algorithm?

TRUST_E_NO_SIGNATURE means the signature is missing or invalid. If the modified bytes are located in the signature block, for example in the certificate store area, that may render the signature invalid without affecting the hash of the file embeded in the signature (in the ContentInfo field on the SignedData structure).

I double checked and the signature is valid.
When I run WinVerifyTrust  without WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG  the error is TRUST_E_BAD_DIGEST
Also signtool verify returns same error.

What signtool parameters did you use to sign the file?

I am testing on wireguard.dll https://download.wireguard.com/wireguard-nt/wireguard-nt-0.10.1.zip
The certificate has EKU Code Signing.
